# How to prevent % signs from ignoring the following 2 charachters

Tags: python, string, url, python-requests

I am trying to use requests to get a links content

`r = requests.get('https://exampleurl.com/search/user_agent=Mozilla%2F5.0(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F84.0.4147.105+Safari%2F537.36`

the % signs ignore the following 2 characters thus the endpoint becomes invalid and returns nothing.

Probably a very beginner question, but any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Python has a feature called 'Raw strings'. You create one by prefixing your string with an `r`. so in your case, it would be:

```
r = requests.get(r'https://exampleurl.com/search/user_agent=Mozilla%2F5.0(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F84.0.4147.105+Safari%2F537.36')
```

Comment: Raw strings only affects backslashes but not percentage signs.